# Emitting a character (or multi-byte binary string) by integer ordinal in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to echo integer in bash as is, without converting each digit to ASCII and outputting corresponding sequence. e.g.

```
echo "123" | hd
00000000  31 32 33 0a                                       |123.|
```

it's outputting ASCII codes of each character. How can I output 123 itself, as unsigned integer for example? so that I get something like

```
00000000  0x7B 00 00 00
```

Comment: If what you want to print is zero-padded int32s (which is what your example makes it look like), you might want to further edit the title yourself to be entirely explicit about that.

Answer (score 2):

That's a job for `printf`

```
$ printf "\x$(printf '%x' "123")" | hd
00000000  7b                                                |{|
```

The internal printf converts the decimal number 123 to hexadecimal and the external printf use `\x` to create a byte with that value.

If you want several bytes, use this:

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\x%x' "123" "96" "68")" | hd
00000000  7b 60 44                                          |{`D|
```

Or, if you want to use hexadecimal:

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\x%x' "0x7f" "0xFF" "0xFF")" | hd
00000000  7f ff ff                                          |...|
```

Or, in this case, simply:

```
$ printf '\x7f\xFF\xFF' | hd
00000000  7f ff ff                                          |...|
```

Comment: Thanks! but how is it possible to output more than 1 byte?  printf "\xFFFF" | hd gives ff 46 46. I want to store it as unsigned integer, 4 bytes.

Comment: `printf '\xFF\xFF'`. It's 2 bytes, not 4

Comment: @ZhaniBaramidze Added a way to print several bytes. Please read it again.

Comment: It does write bytes, not int32. Because of endianess.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful of endianess. x86 is [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Atomic_element_size_8-bit_2) so you must store least significant byte first.

As an example, if you want to store the 32bit integer : 2'937'252'660d = AF'12'EB'34h on disk, you have to write : 0x34, then 0xEB, then 0x12 and then 0xAF, in that order.

Is use this helper for the same purpose as yours:

```
printf "%.4x\n" 2937252660 | fold -b2 | tac | while read a; do echo -e -n "\\x${a}"; done
```

`printf` change from dec base to hex base

`fold` splits by groups of 2 chars, i.e 1 byte

`tac` reverse the lines (this is where little-endian is applied)

`while` loop echo one raw byte at a time

Comment: `echo -e -n` is better replaced with `printf '%b'` -- see [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html), which defines any command with `-n` as having undefined output, and doesn't explicitly specify `-e` at all (but *does* specify that no options are to be permitted other than as-given, meaning that any *compliant* implementation would print `-e` to output; incidentally, bash's own implementation will offer this strictly-compliant behavior if the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options are both enabled).

Comment: ...likewise see the APPLICATION USAGE section of that same document, specifying `printf` as the preferred replacement.

Comment: (This *is* an interesting approach, by the way, and I'm somewhat impressed by it, but it's also wildly inefficient -- running a pipeline for every four bytes is a huge amount of overhead; it's probably worth taking a cut in terseness to do more of the logic internal to the shell if this is ever going to be run over a larger amount of data).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your review. Yes I was about mentioning that it is not design to process massive amount of data, because of new processes and pipes to instantiate for every int.

Comment: Actually endiannes is exactly what I wanted to observe, wanted to know how it would get stored:)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing the observation from [@Setop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41149119/14122) that the examples imply that the OP wants uint32s, but trying to build a more efficient implementation (involving no subshells or external commands):

```
print_byte() {
  local val
  printf -v val '%02x' "$1"
  printf '%b' "\x${val}"
}

print_uint32() {
  print_byte "$(( ( $1 / (( 256 ** 0 )) ) % 256 ))"
  print_byte "$(( ( $1 / (( 256 ** 1 )) ) % 256 ))"
  print_byte "$(( ( $1 / (( 256 ** 2 )) ) % 256 ))"
  print_byte "$(( ( $1 / (( 256 ** 3 )) ) % 256 ))"
}
```

---

Thus:

```
print_uint32 32 | xxd # this should be a single space, padded with nulls
```

...correctly yields:

```
00000000: 2000 0000                                ...
```

...as demonstrated to reverse back to the original value by the Python `struct.unpack()` module:

```
$ print_uint32 32 |
>   python -c 'import struct, sys; print struct.unpack("I", sys.stdin.read())'
32
```